# Groovy 'def' keyword and scope problem in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy, scope

I'm following a groovy tutorial and there is a code like this:

```
def fruit = ["apple", "orange" , "pear"]    //list
def likeIt = { String fruit -> println "I like " + fruit + "s" }    //closure
fruit.each(likeIt)
```

Eclipse reports an error at closure definition line:

> Line breakpoint:SimpleClosuresTest
>   [line: 27] The current scope already
>   contains a variable of the name fruit 
>   @ line 27, column 14.

If i omit 'def' from 'def fruit' Eclipse doesn't complaint and code runs fine.

Could someone explain what is going on with the scopes in both cases?

Thanks.

Comment: the first time I read your code I thought it was a script, then I noticed the SimpleClosuresTest[line: 27]...  
is your example part of a class?

Comment: There is no class explicitly defined, but I wrote this in SimpleClosuresTest.groovy file and groovyc creates class SimpleClosuresTest.class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first a general review of a groovy script:

```
// file: SomeScript.groovy
x = 1
def x = 2
println x
println this.x
```

is roughly compiled as:

```
class SomeScript extends groovy.lang.Script {
  def x
  def run() {
    x = 1
    def x = 2
    println x // 2
    println this.x // 1
  }
}
```

in a groovy script (roughly speaking, a file without the class declaration), assigning a value to an undefined variable is interpreted as a field assignment.

your example tries to defines a closure with a parameter named `fruit`.
if you defined `fruit` with the `def` keyword you get an error message because the name is already taken as a local variable, and you can't duplicate a local variable name.
when you leave the `def` keyword out, you are actually assigning the value to a field of the class generated for the script, and thus the name `fruit` can be redefined as a local variable.

regarding scopes, it's pretty much like java...
in the example, you can see `x` is defined first as a field and then as a variable local to the `run()` method. there's nothing wrong with that and you can access both the variable and the field.
but once you define a local variable, you cannot create duplicates.

edit --
had to add this before anyone gets me wrong: the translation is not exactly like this (thus the "roughly"). Instead of a field you add a value to the binding of the script, quite like `args` for commandline scripts or `request`, `session` or `response` for groovlets.
but that is much a longer story...
ok if you really want to know just ask again and i'll explain it better

edit 2 --
i just can't leave it like this, if you ever need more info...

every groovy script has a field named `binding`, an instance of `groovy.lang.Binding` or one of its a subclasses.
this binding is basically a map, with methods `setVariable` and `setVariable`.
when you omit the `def` keyword when assigning a value in a script you are actually calling the method `setVariable`, and when you do something like `this.x` you are calling the `getVariable` method.
this is actually because class `groovy.lang.Script` overrides the methods `getProperty` and `setProperty` to call those methods first. that's the reason they behave like fields.
you might have also noticed that there is no type associated to those variables... that's because we are dealing with just a `Map` inside the binding.
standard groovy scrips are created with an instance of a binding with the `args` set to the array of parameters.
others, like `groovy.servlet.ServletBinding` define more variables and behavior, like block the assignment of certain variables, or adding a lazy initialization capabilities...

then the real reason behind the error is... if the `def` keyword is not used, `fruits` is not a real variable.  still, i believe the behavior is somewhat analog to a field.

sorry about all that.
i was not satisfied with my own oversimplification :S

Comment: Thank you, it is just the amount of info i wanted at this point.

Answer (score 2):

That String fruit shouldn't be having the same name as your def fruit.  (you are defining first a list and then a string with the same name)

```
def likeIt = { String fruit -> println "I like " + fruit + "s" }
```

In the second case you are defining the type of the variable with def a posteriori, so it works but it is not a good practice as far as I know.

I think that you don't even need to write ->. The groovy manual says that "The -> token is optional and may be omitted if your Closure definition takes fewer than two parameters", which is the case here.

Comment: What is different (with scopes in mind) if I define fruit with def or without it? I'm actually following this book: http://www.amazon.com/Groovy-Domain-Specific-Languages-Fergal-Dearle/dp/184719690X why are doing it "the wrong way" (according to you)?

Comment: "def" is a replacement for a type name. In variable definitions it is used to indicate that you don't care about the type. In variable definitions it is mandatory to either provide a type name explicitly or to use "def" in replacement. So if you define fruit as a dynamic type with "def fruit", there is no point on making it a strong-typed variable in "String fruit" (which by the way doesn't make sense in a 1 parameter closure). Try def likeIt = { println "I like " + it + "s" } fruit.each(likeIt) (it is the default name of the parameter for 1 parameter closures).

Comment: Tnx. But still - i would very much like to find out something about the scopes in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Second line

> String fruit

the same variable name 'fruit' is being used again